# Fatal error: all goroutines are asleep deadlock in writing to multiple channels

Tags: go, goroutine

I just started learning to go routines, I am trying to write to two channels in one go routine which generates even and odd numbers till 50. However, I am getting deadlock.

Here's the code, what am I doing wrong?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func generateNumbers(wg *sync.WaitGroup, evenChannel, oddChannel chan<- int) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for i := 1; i <= 50; i++ {
        if i%2 == 1 {
            oddChannel <- i
        } else {
            evenChannel <- i
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    evenChannel := make(chan int)
    oddChannel := make(chan int)
    wg.Add(1)
    go generateNumbers(&wg, evenChannel, oddChannel)
    wg.Wait()
    for {
        select {
        case evenNum, ok := <-evenChannel:
            if ok {
                fmt.Println("Even Number:", evenNum)
            } else {
                evenChannel = nil
            }
        case oddNum, ok := <-oddChannel:
            if ok {
                fmt.Println("Odd Number:", oddNum)
            } else {
                oddChannel = nil
            }
        }
        if evenChannel == nil && oddChannel == nil {
            break
        }
    }
    close(evenChannel)
    close(oddChannel)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing a lot of thing in here.

**First Deadlock**

```
wg.Wait() vs  oddChannel <- i
```

You are waiting to the goRoutine to finish and the goRoutine will wait until channel got received by other goRoutine in your scenario main.

**Second Deadlock**

On Main function you are closing the channels. You will never escape the foor loop! So this should be on `generateNumbers` function

```
close(evenChannel)
close(oddChannel)
```

Final Code :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func generateNumbers(wg *sync.WaitGroup, evenChannel, oddChannel chan<- int) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for i := 1; i <= 50; i++ {
        if i%2 == 1 {
            oddChannel <- i
        } else {
            evenChannel <- i
        }
    }
    close(evenChannel)
    close(oddChannel)
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    evenChannel := make(chan int)
    oddChannel := make(chan int)
    wg.Add(1)
    go generateNumbers(&wg, evenChannel, oddChannel)

    for {
        select {
        case evenNum, ok := <-evenChannel:
            if ok {
                fmt.Println("Even Number:", evenNum)
            } else {
                evenChannel = nil
            }
        case oddNum, ok := <-oddChannel:
            if ok {
                fmt.Println("Odd Number:", oddNum)
            } else {
                oddChannel = nil
            }
        }
        if evenChannel == nil && oddChannel == nil {
            break
        }
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("FINISH")
}
```

Comment: Fewer sweeping changes than my suggestion :D

Answer (score 0):

```golang
evenChannel := make(chan int)
```

Your problem is with your channels.  Both are blocking channels (no dimensionality) meaning after you have pushed a value to it it will block until that value is read.  Combine this with your `wg.Wait()` before reading from the channel and you have your deadlock.

Try this instead; https://go.dev/play/p/qbu81j_fgKt

This way we leave the checking of channel close to the loop through the range expression, the wait group is checking for each of the three goroutines to finish.